# prettyPhoto: how to dynamically add photos to open gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, photo-gallery

I have an image-gallery using prettyPhoto. I use the api for loading the photos in it. 
The first photo is available in a data-attribute on the thumbnail. The rest of the images are being fetched with an AJAX-call.

The first photo of the album (the one that is already in the DOM) is being shown perfectly. But in the success-function of the AJAX call I'm reloading the gallery with the new images. That part isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:** (I removed unnecassary elements)

```
<a href="/images/test.jpg" class="albumTrigger" rel="129">
  <img src="/images/test.jpg?rwidth=100&quality=100" id="thumbImage5418" class="thumbImage" data-album='[{"description":"","name":"test.jpg","id":5418,"url":"\/images\/test.jpg"}]'>
</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('#gallery').on('click','.albumTrigger',function(e) {
  // initialize gallery
  $.fn.prettyPhoto({ 
    slideShow: 3000, 
    theme: 'dark_rounded',
    social_tools: ''
  });

  var api_images = [];
  var api_titles = [];
  var api_descriptions = [];
  var albumData = $(this).find('.thumbImage').data('album');
  $.each(albumData,function(index,item) {
    api_images.push(item.url);
    api_titles.push(item.name);
    api_descriptions.push(item.wf_description);
  });
  $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);

  // Get rest of images via ajax
  $.get('/gallery',{
    'id': $(this).attr('rel'),
    'method': 'getAlbumImages'
  },function(albumData) {
    // I did console.log(albumData); here, and there was data
    // add images to gallery
    $.each(albumData,function(index,item) {
      api_images.push(item.url);
      api_titles.push(item.name);
      api_descriptions.push(item.description);
    });
    $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);

  });

  e.preventDefault();

});
```

**EDIT:**

If I remove the first block of code what opens prettyPhoto it works perfect. But now the gallery opens after the ajax-call has run.
The idea kinda is that while the ajax-call is running, the user already sees the album-photo.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your second .open call to first close the gallery then open it again:

```
$.prettyPhoto.close();
$.prettyPhoto.open(...);
```